# How can I set up a static form for adding associated records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms, nested-resources

I have the following models I'm using...

**Game**

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :workout
  has_many :participations

end
```

**Participation**

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :game

end
```

**Workout**

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :game
  has_many   :measurables

end
```

**Measurable**

```
class Measurable < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :workout

end
```

`Workout` is currently a nested resource for `Player`. Usually, I would create a `Workout` record on a `Player` one at a time.  I would also add the `Measurable`s to the `Workout` using the gem [nested_fields_for](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields) but this would allow me to add/remove just one measurable at a time, for one player at a time.  I'm trying to now build a form for a user to edit multiple measurables for every player that is participating in a game.

**Example Form**

```
Player            |    Height   |    Weight    |   Hand Span  |
Player 1's Name     [input box]   [input box]     [input box]
Player 2's Name     [input box]   [input box]     [input box]
Player 3's Name     [input box]   [input box]     [input box]
Player 4's Name     [input box]   [input box]     [input box]
```

I've so far created a view under my views/games directory for `edit_measurables.rb` and an action in `games_controller` called #edit_measurables. I was planning to create_or_find the `Workout` that corresponds to the `Game` here and build the form shown above.  Though I'm not sure where to go from here.  It has me thinking I have something incorrectly organized with my models and associations.

**Update:**

I've managed to get a little further along, but I'm still running into a few issues, albeit some outside the scope of this question.

The form I'm wanting to construct I'm trying to handle in the following way...

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>Hand</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @game.participations.each do |participant| %>
      <% player = participant.player %>

      <% simple_form_for participant.player do |player_form| %>
        <% workout = Workout.find_or_create_by(...) %>
        <% @measurables.each {|m| workout.measurables.build(...) unless workout.measurables.any? { ... } } %>

      <tr>
        <td><%= player.full_name %></td>

        <% player_form.nested_fields_for :measurables, workout.measurables, wrapper_tag: :td do |measurable_form| %>
          <td><%= measurable_form.input :value, label: false %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you got any code yet? I have code which would give you what you need, but it would not be able to add dynamic values etc

Comment: `<% game.participations.each do |participation| %>
  <% workout = participation.game.workout %>
  <%= form_for participation.player do |player_form| %>
    <%= fields_for player.measureables.where(workout: workout) do |measurable_form| %>
      <%= measurable_form.text_field :height %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>`  this will mean I need to have submit buttons for each row though I think -- which is not what I want..

Comment: Thanks, let me write an answer. It probably won't be what you need but might give ideas

Comment: Sure thanks! And I've gotten a little further along, if you'd like me to update my original post with where I am currently I can -- but maybe for what you planned on posting it doesn't matter.

Comment: Just spend the past 40 mins on this, it's hard

Comment: I feel like i've got a fundamental issue with my model/objects structure since it's been this hard to make a "simple" form.  I'm just not sure yet what it is.  Usually when I find myself working this much towards something such as this -- that seems to be the biggest problem.  I'll update my original post right quick.

Comment: Available for chat if required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% game.participations.each do |participation| %>
  <% workout = participation.game.workout %>
  <%= form_for participation.player do |player_form| %>
    <%= fields_for player.measureables.where(workout: workout) do |measurable_form| %>
      <%= measurable_form.text_field :height %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So what you're doing is giving a `player` a set of `measurables` for each `workout`, of which a `game` has one?

The *problem* here is that you've not associated the `measurables` to your `game` & `player`, especially through `participations`. I think this is why you're seeing the problem; your `measurables` have to be pulled from another unrelated table.

If that is the case, why not put the measurables in the `participation` model?

The "has_one" workout would mean only one workout for the game... which means that the game could `belong_to` a workout?? If that was the case, someone participating in a game would be able to store their measurables for *that* game in their `Participation` model...

--

```
#app/views/games/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :participations do |p| %>
       <%= p.object.player.name unless p.object.new_record? %>
       <%= p.collection_select :player_id, Player.all, :id, :name if p.object.new_record? %>
       <%= p.number_field :measurable_height %>
       <%= p.number_field :measurable_weight %>
       <%= p.number_field :measurable_hand_span %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to associate `measurables` directly:

```
#app/models/game.rb
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :workout
   has_many   :participations
   has_many   :players, through: :participations
end

#app/models/participation.rb
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
   #id | player_id | game_id | measurable_height | measurable_weight | measurable_hand_span | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :player
   belongs_to :game
end
```

With the following controller:

```
#app/controllers/games_controller.rb
class GamesController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @game = Game.new
     @game.participations.build #-> this would be needed to "add" extra fields
   end

   def edit
     @game = Game.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
     @game = Game.find params[:id]
     @game.update update_params
   end

   private

   def update_params
     params.require(:game).permit(partipations_attributes: [:measurable_height, :measurable_weight, :measurable_hand_span])
   end
end
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time-- let me look into it.  Something I will note that I hadn't known until I starting trying to figure out this problem was the workout association *should* have been a has_many, not a has_one.

Comment: Okay well that puts my answer into jeopardy. Can you tell me more about `games` / `workouts` & how they work together?

Comment: `workout` belongs_to a `game` and a `player`.  Each `game` has a set of `participant`s.  What I'm attempting to describe is a Football Game.  At this game different players will participate in it, but also there will be a "workout" where each player is measured on many different things (ex: height, weight, hand span, arm length, etc.)  Some will elect not to measure for certain things though.  What I'm trying to do with the form is build out a input box for all the possibilities of specific measurables I choose for each player. So the user can tab through typing in all the values.